# Is there a way to remove my item from the Scanner in java?

Tags: java

I am creating a reaction time program and everything works as it should, but if the user hits enter before GO is printed to the console, the program skips right passed input.nextLine() and they get a 1ms reaction time. Does anybody have an idea on how this can be fixed?

```
    System.out.println("3");
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    System.out.println("2");
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    System.out.println("1");
    Thread.sleep(rand.nextInt(2000) + 1000);
    System.out.println("GO");

    // Get the start time
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    // Wait for user input
    input.nextLine();

    // Get stop time
    long stopTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    // Calculate the reaction time in ms
    long reactionTime = stopTime - startTime;

    // Print the reaction time to the console
    System.out.println(reactionTime + "ms");
```

Comment: Try to add this line just after the `'GO'`: `System.in.read(new byte[System.in.available()]);` if you use `Scanner` with `System.in`

Comment: Thank you thibsc!